# Matching multiple target values to get multiple range.values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set range.values for multiple cells based on the target values of the respective cells.
For instance I want to clear a cell when the cell beside it is changed. This logic has to be applied for respective cells throughout the column.

```
    If Target.Address = "$D$7" Then
        Range("E7").Value = ""
    End If
```

In the above code, if D7 is changed E7 will be cleared. Now I want to do the same for all the cells below them like if D8 is changed E8 should be cleared, when D9 is changed E9 should be cleared and so on. Every set of cells should be independent to each other. In other words, if D8 is changed, then it should not clear E9, it should only clear E8.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Use `Offset` - `Target.Offset(,1)`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and put it in the code that I put above, I am new to VBA

Comment: `Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D5:D100")): If Not rng Is nothing then rng.offset(0,1).ClearContents`

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the edited range only to your range of interest using `Application.Intersect`:

```vb
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D5:D100")) 'adjust monitored range as needed
If Not rng Is nothing Then 
    rng.offset(0, 1).ClearContents
End If
```